# Is it SEO compatible to set the page title with JavaScript at load time?

Tags: seo, javascript

I want to change some page elements with JS like title h1,h2,h3, p tags and so on.

So I want to place in my code something like

```
 $(function() {
     document.title = "This is the new page title."
});
```

So will it be SEO compatible?
I have read some questions like this [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title) and  [Can I randomly change the page title for users while showing search engines a static title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95555/can-i-randomly-change-the-page-title-for-users-while-showing-search-engines-a-st) Some say that it will won't work, but some say that it will work because now google indexes js.

So will it be SEO compatible?

UPD: I want to change title for user and for google bots, for both of them.Just once on page load.
 There is always the same h1 for everybody, the changed title is the same for everybody.

Long story:

I need this because I am writing a js plugin.
Something like cms but on our hosting.
Client inputs there h1,h2,h3,h4 title and so on using recomendation of our seo improving program.
He inserts at the end of page script, and script  using some api get this values from our server and changes the page.

I know it is somekind of too much complicated. But if it works it will give more customers because customer is lazy and he doesn't won't to make changes in the website by himself sometimes websites don't have cms and he doesn't know html. So this script can be considered like external cms and in theory make customer's life simplier

Comment: Do you want your title to be changed "dynamically" on google serps or just for the user? Can you give us an example use case or rule which triggers the change? Like, are there different H1 headlines for users with a certain referral?

Comment: @MiloTischler I want to change title for user and for google bots, for both of them.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/98244/43910

Comment: @MiloTischler see upd

Comment: @Evgeniy I didn't  really get it. You say that when you fetch as google you don't see changes. But actually google bot indexes this changes?

Comment: Are you changing the title as the page gets used, or just using setting it once using JavaScript on page load?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller just once on page load.

Comment: @user2950593: the sense of that all is: everything loaded before `onLoad` == no problem with indexation. the later is something is loaded after `onLoad`, the lesser chances for it to be indexed

Comment: @user2950593 empirically tested maximal time gap after `onLoad` is about 4 seconds: https://builtvisible.com/javascript-framework-seo/

Answer (score 2):

I went to https://nerdydata.com and did a search for `document.title = "`.
Then i searched for a result with a difference between `title` and `document.title`. I found: http://www.ipts.com/

[image]

So i checked Google with `site:http://www.ipts.com/` and got the result:

[image]

.. so sometimes Google uses / tests other text on the website as title, but the JS `document.title` is the only location that exact string seems to appear:

[image]

**Conclusion:**
It seems likely that you can set the title via JS. But don't forget, that Google tests other text on your website as title. Maybe even JS strings? With that in mind, i think: If the title "set with JS" is better for Google than the original `<title>` they will use it.